# Vuejs v-model not updating

Tags: vue.js

My "hello" data property is not updating whenever I update the value in the text field. The value in {{hello}} should change as I modify the value in the text field. Here is a video that demonstrates what I'm trying to do: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9rmfaA-ndak

```
<div id="app">
  <example></example>
</div>

<template id="template">
  <input type="text" placeholder="target env" id="field_target_env" :v-model="hello">{{ hello }}
</template>
```

```
Vue.component('example', {
  template: '#template',
  data() {
    return {
        hello: '242'
    }
  }
});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

Here is runnable
jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3akv5e4f/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the colon for the v-model attribute of your input, and it should looks something like:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      hello: 'Hello World!'
    };
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h1>{{ hello }}</h1>
  <input id="field_target_env" type="text" placeholder="target env" v-model="hello" />
</div>
```

The colon before an attribute is to bind data on attribute that is not initially planned for, like "placeholder" or "value" for example. But the v-model attribute is already planned to take data from your Vue app and don't need that.

In my example, I've remove your component part to focus on your main question, about the v-model

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the colon before v-model in your code. It is only needed when you do the shorthand expressions.

Comment: Ah yes... Thank you. Time to go to sleep.